# Best way to get a javascript function that applies an iteratee function to a list?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Let's say I have an iteratee function that takes an item and returns an item, such as used for `map`, `each` functions etc.

Silly example:

```
function nameConverter(item) {
    return {
        fullName: item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName;
    }
}
```

If I have a function taking a callback or having a promise for an item, it's easy to just pass the `nameConverter` function directly:

```
return getPerson().then(nameConverter);
```

However, quite frequently I find myself in a situation where I also need a function taking a list, that iterates over the list with said iteratee function. It's of course very simple to create a one-liner function each time for this:

```
return listPersons().then(function(persons) {
    return persons.map(nameConverter);
});
```

When doing this frequently it bothered me that there wasn't a shorter syntax, so I created a helper function:

```
function mapper(iteratee) {
    return function(list) {
        return _.map(list, iteratee);
    }
}
```

which allowed me to do

```
return listPersons().then(mapper(nameConverter));
```

I then further generalized this into:

```
function iterator(iterate, iteratee) {
    return function(list) {
        return iterate(list, iteratee);
    }
}
```

so that I could do the same thing for both `map`, `each`, `filter` or whatever underscore/lodash function:

```
return listPersons().then(iterator(_.map, nameConverter));
```

However, I am curious if there is a better way, such a standard Javascript function or something in underscore/lodash already that does the same thing? It seems like such a common case...

Comment: I quite like your solution. It looks good with some ES6 as well: `return listPersons().then(persons => persons.map(nameConverter));`

Comment: Have a look at the currying functions in lodash. The iterator could be replaced with `_.curryRight(_.map, nameConverter)`

Comment: That's clever. I did look at currying, but it wasn't obvious to me right away that this would be the result. I think a dedicated function _.applyList or something would have been a reasonable addition to lodash. :-)

Comment: @GruffBunny I'm happy to accept your suggestion if you supply at as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iterator` function is effectively doing what lodash's [**partialRight**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partialRight) function does i.e. partially applies the rightmost argument to a function.

So in the example above, `_.partialRight` is a drop in replacement for `iterator`:

```
return listPersons().then(_.partialRight(_.map, nameConverter));
```

NB The comment I added to the question incorrectly uses [**curryRight**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#curryRight) where it should be [**partialRight**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partialRight). `curryRight` is similar but returns a function where the arguments are applied after the function is first curried:

```
let curriedConverter = _.curryRight(_.map);
curriedConverter(nameConverter)
```

or (the uglier)

```
let curriedConverter = _.curryRight(_.map)(nameConverter);
```

So the iterator replacement then becomes

```
return listPersons().then(_.curryRight(_.map)(nameConverter))); // yuk
```